# Categories and Subcategories Android

Tags: android

I have an application where i want to show categories and subcategories, sub-sub-categories and so on depending on a database.

What I would like is to show it in graphical mode so that the user can navigate between the categories to see the articles inside easily.

¿Anyone knows which control-layout can I use to show the categories?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a Custom Expandable ListView with "n" levels. Basically [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) comes out with two levels. One is the parent Group and other is the Child Group. Clicking on your Parent enables you to view your Child Group. But since you are looking for sub-sub-category you have to modify the adapter to work for you. Here is a very good example which helps you to achieve it.

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2011/02/3-level-expandable-lists.html

http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/